# Number Field Default Value Not Retained When Adding Table Row

Tags: apex, visualforce

How can I retain default value in number field each time I add a row in table?

I just noticed that default value only shows once, but when I add new row, the number field is blank.

Note that I set the default value to 0.

Meanwhile, here are the controller and the vf page:

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class creatingListOfRecordsController {

    public list<Account> accountList{get;set;}
    public list<Accountwrapper> accountwrapperList{get;set;}
    public Integer counter{get;set;}

    public creatingListOfRecordsController(){
           counter = 0;
           accountList = new list<Account>(); 
           accountwrapperList = new list<Accountwrapper>();
           for(Integer i=0;i<5;i++){
               Accountwrapper actWrap = new Accountwrapper(new Account()); 
               counter++;
               actWrap.counterWrap = counter;
               accountwrapperList.add(actWrap); 

           }

    }

    public PageReference addRow(){
        //accountList.add(new Account());
        Accountwrapper actWrap = new Accountwrapper(new Account()); 

        counter++;
        actWrap.counterWrap = counter; 
        accountwrapperList.add(actWrap); 
        return null;    
    }
    public PageReference removingRow(){

        Integer param = Integer.valueOf(Apexpages.currentpage().getParameters().get('index'));

        for(Integer i=0;i<accountwrapperList.size();i++){
            if(accountwrapperList[i].counterWrap == param ){
                accountwrapperList.remove(i);     
            }
        }


        counter--;
        return null;    
    }

    public PageReference saving(){
        list<Account> updateAccountList;
        updateAccountList = new list<Account>();
        if(!accountwrapperList.isEmpty()){
            for(Accountwrapper accountWrapper:accountwrapperList){
                updateAccountList.add(accountWrapper.account);
            }
        }
        if(!updateAccountList.isEmpty()){
            upsert updateAccountList;
        }
       ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,'Record Saved Successfully.');
       ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
        return null;
    }

    public class Accountwrapper{
        public Account account{get;set;}
        public Integer counterWrap{get;set;}

        public Accountwrapper(Account act){
            this.account = act;  

        }
    }

}
```

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="creatingListOfRecordsController">
    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageBlock title="Creating List Of Account Records">
        <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton value="Add Row" action="{!addRow}" reRender="table" immediate="true"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accountwrapperList}" var="page" id="table"> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!page.account.name}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Phone">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!page.account.Phone}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Sample Number">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!page.account.Sample__c}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Delete" action="{!removingRow}" immediate="true">
                            <apex:param name="index" value="{!page.counterWrap}"/>  
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saving}" />

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In add row method this line update it

```
Accountwrapper actWrap = new Accountwrapper(new Account(Sample__c = 0));
```

So it will by default take 0. You can update it to any number.

Comment: hey, thanks a ton! I didn't know that it's that simple :)